# Custom mobile theme

Tags: wordpress

Okay,

So I figured out on my own how to make a mobile site out of an Artisteer template.

Basically, I changed the sheet to 100% fluid width, minimum 300 px, one column, got rid of the menu and replaced it with a vertical menu, got rid of most of the blocks or put them under the vertical menu, made everything smaller and simpler. Smaller fonts, got rid of most of the padding except for 3px, made the header shorter, made the vertical menu bars tall enough to press with a finger, etc. My new mobile-friendly site looks great.

So now what? Do I export it as a WordPress theme and then have two installations of WordPress for every website?

Or do I export it as html, use a redirect WordPress plugin, an add an RSS feed?

Hmm...I think I may try html, but would love some feedback anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want two installations of Wordpress... double the admin overhead, duplicate content etc - not the way to go.

Easiest way IMO - and indeed, this is the way recommended by some commercial mobile theme developers - is to use a plugin like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mobile-theme-switcher/ which simply detects the user agent of the client's device and switches to your mobile theme if it's a mobile device.  So one Wordpress installation, two themes.

I know recommending a pluign isn't really the SO way :) - you can always look through the code and integrate it directly into your theme if you needed to.

Comment: hi mcnab thanks for quick reply.  the thing is my desktop site is very content and image heavy.  i just want to create a seperate mobile site with just 5 out of 50 pages and to have only 100 words per page instead of 2000. take this website for example: webpagefx.com

Comment: Ah, I see. Well remember that your mobile theme doesn't have to give the user access to all the content in the Wordpress installation, you can tailor it to display whatever you like. It's own nav, pages, posts etc.  However, if the content is markedly different then it probably makes sense to have it as a separate installation on a subdomain or subdirectory and redirect the user there if they are on a mobile device. Plenty of plugins for that too.

Comment: QUOTE> " then it probably makes sense to have it as a separate installation on a subdomain or subdirectory and redirect the user there if they are on a mobile device.<QUOTE  how would i go about doing this. im a noob. thanks in advance

Comment: You create a subdomain, install wordpress, install your mobile theme add your different content.  So you have a full mobile site running on http://m.yourdomain.com .  You install a plugin like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-mobile-url-redirect/ on the main site to redirect to the mobile site for mobiles.  There are SEO issues with all of this, read up on it http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/making-websites-mobile-friendly.html