# Creating a mobile version of Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, mobile, tablet

How can I create a mobile version of an existing Wordpress site?

I understand that I can use mobile specific style sheets but how can I adjust the actual template files so there's two versions, one for desktop and one for mobile?

It's not a case of making the site responsive because it's using only parts of the same information. Also, the site is more complicated than just using the various Wordpress mobile plugins.

Is there a way to load a different part of the template depending if it's mobile or desktop? So it'll be using the same template.

Comment: Please refer the link http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-develop-wordpress-mobile-version-of-site

Comment: I answered a similar question 2 days ago, it might be helpful -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677636/custom-mobile-theme/14677731#14677731

Answer (score 0):

a little outdated, but this explains how tis was done using WPtouch
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/how-to-detect-mobile-devices-and-present-them-a-specific-theme

than you can load stylesheet/ theme based on mobile browser (although this would use different templates or CSS files etc)

```
if ( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin' ) === false ) {
    add_filter( 'stylesheet', array(&$this, 'get_stylesheet') );
    add_filter( 'theme_root', array(&$this, 'theme_root') );
    add_filter( 'theme_root_uri', array(&$this, 'theme_root_uri') );
    add_filter( 'template', array(&$this, 'get_template') );       
}
```